# 504 Gateway Time-out - upstream timeout

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

Everything was running smoothly when suddenly my server stopped working.
I'm using Linode with Nginx fast-cgi

This is my log file:

upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 76.66.174.147, server: iskacanada.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.iskacanada.com"

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

When I want to restart mysql it says:

sudo service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a few hours of Debugging here is how I did it:

Using Ubuntu 12.04, Nginx and php5-fmp

1. PLease check your log files! log files are your friends. a 504 Gateway problem means that my server is not communicating properly with the website. So In my case I had Nginx and php-fpm that was managing the requests. I had to check 2 log files:

   /var/log/nginx/error.log  and /var/log/php5-fpm.log

in error.log:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 76.66.174.147, server: xxxxxxx.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.xxxxxxx.com"
```

in php5-fpm.log:

unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (98)

So I figured out that I needed to check my php5-fpm process by typing

```
netstat | grep 9000
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:58424 SYN_RECV   
tcp      913      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:57917 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp      857      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:58032 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp     1633      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:58395 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp      961      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:58025 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp      857      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:58040 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp      953      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:58005 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp      761      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:58016 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp     1137      0 localhost.localdom:9000 localhost.localdo:57960 CLOSE_WAIT
```

Lots of close_wait!!! that's abnormal...so I killed all the processes by typing
fuser -k 9000/tcp

I then changed my

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

and changing this:

request_terminate_timeout=30s

Now the website works. I hope this solved the problem since it was intermittent.

Comment: Very useful, thank you. Other things to do are set listen.backlog to a higher value in fpm conf and also sysctl net.core.somaxconn to a higher value as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check if PHP is still running: `sudo ps aux | grep php`

If it is, restart it `sudo service php5-fpm restart` if not start it `sudo service php5-fpm start`.

If you need to restart your database only pass `restart`, `stop` or `start` to the `service` command: `sudo service mysql start` or `sudo service mysql restart` or `sudo service mysql stop`.

Comment: Many thanks :) php5-fpm is restarting well. Now I have a 502  Bad Gateway error!

Comment: it now says  sudo service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start

Comment: Check the error log of your mysql installation. Usually at `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, you can post the last few lines in your question and let me know so I can help you with that.

Comment: Many Thanks Fleshgrinder. The error.log file does not exist. I tried adding it in my my.cnf file but can't restart mysql (service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start
)

Comment: OK I finally unable the error log for mysql and I got this: 131017 09:47:00 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

Comment: I rebooted my VPS and restarted my Nginx and php5-fpm and I am getting  .. Error establishing a database connection. I feel i'm getting somewhere :)

Comment: OK now the website works for a strange reason. Lets see if it's still on in a few hours.

Answer (score -1):

I just installed winginx and had the 504 gateway problem. The error log pointed at the upstream server "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000". This is where nginx proxies to php.

I opened the php-cgi.conf and found that php was listening on port 9054. Changed the port to 9000 and all is well.

Gateway is the route and/or port that nginx uses to connect to a service. For instance, Mongodb is configured to listen on port 27017 out of the box. For security reasons, I tend to change the default ports on services such as php etc. on production servers.